# Calling a Lua function from within an object instance

Tags: function, class, object, lua, coronasdk

I have a Main lua file that creates a scene and within the scene function it creates a Deck object and a function called wonGame() that check to see when the game is won.

```
local composer = require("composer")
function scene:create(e)
     require "Deck"
     myDeck = Deck:new()

     function wonGame()
         print("You have won the game")
     end
end
```

My question - how can I call the wonGame() function from within the Deck class file? For example, say I have a function called checkCondition in Deck class

```
function checkCondition(e) 
    if(somethingTrue)
         wonGame() --this should be the function in Main file
    end
end
```

Comment: You are always forgetting the `self`-parameter. Also, shouldn't `wonGame` be a member of `Deck`?

Comment: My head hurts thinking of how this is designed. What is a scene and deck? What is the game that is being played? How do they related to one another? As of now, the function wonGame falls out-of-scope after the create function is called.

Comment: I believe that what he has is correct though. wonGame should not be implemented in Deck. The Deck should probably just be a collection of Cards I assume and would have no knowledge about the game that it's in.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try and implement a delegate: [Wikipedia](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Delegation_(programming))

Basically this means you have a property in 'Deck' that links back to 'Scene'. When you create your Deck you would set something like

```
Deck.SceneDelegate = self
```

Then in Deck you could just call

```
SceneDelegate.wonGame()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two things:

1. Deck must be designed to call a user-defined callback
2. You must register your callback to the Deck instance

Requirement 1 means that somewhere in the Deck code, you have code to call `self.onWonGame`. I don't know how Deck is defined but it could be something like this:

```
function Deck:doSomething()
    ...
    -- if some condition is verified, and the onWonGame callback has been defined, call it: 
    if self.someCondition and self.onWonGame then 
         self.onWonGame()  
    end
    ...
end
```

Requirement 2 means that you need a data member or method to set the callback. Example:

```
function Deck:setWonGameCallback(callback)
    self.onWonGame = callback
end
```

The above examples will only allow one callback to be defined for a Deck instance. You would need self.onWonGame to be  table of callbacks if you want more than one callback, then in the `doSomething` you would loop over the table and call each one. Also, in the example above each instance would have to get `setWonGameCallback()` called upon it. If you want all instance to use the same callback, you would have to define the callback in the class rather than instance.